# Jenkinsfile - use if statement in post failure stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I would like to have an if statement in my failure {} stage under post {} stage.

I have tried the following different ways:

```
    post {
        cleanup {
            cleanWs()
        }

        failure {
            step {
                script {
                    if ( JOB_NAME.contains("myjob") ) {
                        // do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error is:

```
WorkflowScript: 372: Missing required parameter: "delegate" @ line 372, column 13.
               step {
               ^
```

Second attempt:

```
    post {
        cleanup {
            cleanWs()
        }

        failure {
            steps {
                script {
                    if ( JOB_NAME.contains("myjob") ) {
                        // do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps
```

Third attempt:

```
    post {
        cleanup {
            cleanWs()
        }

        failure {
            step (
                    if ( JOB_NAME.contains("myjob") ) {
                        // do something
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
WorkflowScript: 373: unexpected token: if @ line 373, column 21.
                       if ( JOB_NAME.contains("streampilot-ci") ) {
```

Anyone know how to get a if statement in the failure{} section correctly?
I am running 2.204 or Jenkins

Comment: I do not believe `steps` are allowed within `post` like that. You could try a `script` block directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `step` in the conditions. See the official [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post).

```
post {
    cleanup {
        cleanWs()
    }
    failure {
        script {
            if ( JOB_NAME.contains("myjob") ) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```